# Streamline Facebook and Google Play Game Services integration in Android Game

Tags: android, facebook, social, google-play-services

This has been confusing me a lot .

I am creating a simple 2D platformer which I wish to make social. So I thought of letting users do the following:

- Share their in game objective completion/ their high score etc with their friends.
- Challenge their friends to have a better score / better multiplier etc from their's
- View leaderboards of high score , most distance traveled etc both social and global.

So My First preference was Facebook , simply because people have better social connections there.

But then Google Play game services integration has another advantage, It makes you game available in their game services app and may be boost your game ranking in play store if you have game services integrated. But then I'' need to have leaderboards(same ones) for google plus as well. That 'll be too confusing for people.

I do not want people to sign in twice in my app. That'll simple cut down and disperse the number of people getting social with the game.

I personally want to use facebook alone but then google game services may be boosts my app in store.

Can someone tell me a solution to use them both frictionlessly and get the most out of them in my game

Answer (score 1):

I was earlier in the same confusion and finally found out there is no proper solution for this.
My consideration for Google play was not for ranking but for using the leaderboards and multiplayer features. And again If I go with Google Play Services alone, I miss a-lot with Facebook login.

So you decide which has more weightage and pick one of it. If you are targeting only for Android I suggest going alone for Google Play services as most of the users will have an account.

I picked Parse.com and implemented my own leaderboards and used Facebook for logging in (as I targeted iOS as well, I see FB has more reach).

In between, I tried OpenKit and dropped as its getting closed soon. Now i'm checking NextPeer which is a bit close enough to solve my problem. Will update once I play with NextPeer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Even if I am initially launching my game for android alone , I guess people are more engaged seeing their facebook friends there instead of google plus circle people. May be I am wrong

Comment: Even though Google play services solved the issue(Gamecenter not being crossplatform) of getting cross-platform gaming, it restricted its login style to gmail alone. Do you have any links for saying Google will promote if Google Play Services is included? if not its of much importance and if you see FB has more reach, go with some third party libraries or use Parse to build your own. Finally its a decision which is based on your games target audience.